# maximal planar bipartite graphs

Tags: graph-theory

I know that a maximal planar graph is a graph in which no more segments can be added to connect more vertices because then it won't be planar, but I trying to define what a maximal planar bipartite graph is.

Answer (score 2):

I found [this paper](https://www.math.washington.edu/~novik/publications/BalancedRigidity.pdf) that, among other things, gives a definition for a maximal planar bipartite graph.

A graph, G, is maximal planar bipartite if the addition of any edge results in either a non-planar graph or a non-bipartite graph.

They go on to prove a theorem that amounts to the fact that any maximal planar graph, when embedded on the plane, has that every region is a 4-cycle.  This is in contrast to a maximal planar graph where we know that every region must be a 3-cycle.